# Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list3

Tags: javascript

```
var yourName;   //global variable accessible to all functions
function showAnotherMessage() {
    alert("Hi " + yourName  ".\nThis is an alert message is no longer defined\nin the HTML but in a JavaScript file");
}

function init() {
    yourName = Prompt("Hi. Enter your name.\nWhen the browser window is first loaded\nthe function containing this prompt window is called.", "Your name");
    clickme = document.getElementById("clickme");
    clickme.onclick = showAnotherMessage;

    }

window.onload = init();
```

Comment: Please show a [mcve], explaining what line of code has the syntax error.

Answer (score 2):

```
function showAnotherMessage() {
    alert("Hi " + yourName + ".\nThis is an alert message is no longer defined\nin the HTML but in a JavaScript file");
}
```

you miss a "+" in your alert.

Answer (score 0):

Pass to the `window.onload` not the **result** of the function, but the **reference** of the function and add missed `+` in the alert's message

```
alert("Hi " + yourName + ".\nThis is an alert message is no longer defined\nin the HTML but in a JavaScript file");
```

Reference

`window.onload = init;`

Comment: Must be something else! Coz the error is still there

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a `+` in your alert concatenation.
`alert("Hi " + yourName + ".\nThis is an alert message is no longer defined\nin the HTML but in a JavaScript file");`

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a concatenation.
Prompt should be in lower case.

```
var yourName;   //global variable accessible to all functions
function showAnotherMessage() {
    alert("Hi " + yourName + ".\nThis is an alert message is no longer defined\nin the HTML but in a JavaScript file");
}

function init() {
    yourName = prompt("Hi. Enter your name.\nWhen the browser window is first loaded\nthe function containing this prompt window is called.", "Your name");
    clickme = document.getElementById("clickme");
    clickme.onclick = showAnotherMessage;

    }

window.onload = init();
```

Answer (score 0):

if the issue is still there,, then it is related to calling the function

```
 clickme.onclick = showAnotherMessage;
// instead use below
 clickme.onclick = showAnotherMessage();
```